# Why does $g$ show up in the frequency of this oscillation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, spring, oscillators

The problem diagram is given in the picture below:

[image]

Having looked at this question [Why does the acceleration $g$ due to gravity not affect the period of a vertically mounted spring?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/145781/) something troubles me about the solution given in the solution manual for this specific problem. Here is how it goes.
We rotate the door a small angle $θ$ as shown in the picture:

[image]

Taking the sum of the torques around the center of rotation we have: 
$$I\ddot θ=-mgθ\frac{L}{4}-mgθx-k\frac{l}{4}θ\frac{l}{4}-k\frac{l}{4}θ\frac{l}{4}\\=>(m\frac{l^2}{12}+Mx^2+m(\frac{l}{4})^2)\ddot θ + (mg\frac{L}{4}+Mgx+k\frac{l^2}{8})θ=0\\=>\ddot θ+\frac{mg\frac{L}{4}+Mgx+k\frac{l^2}{8}}{m\frac{l^2}{12}+Mx^2+m(\frac{l}{4})^2}θ=0$$ We can clearly see that the $ω^2$ which is the coefficient of $θ$ depends on g which contradicts what is said in the linked question. Is the solution wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not contradict the (correct) result for the other problem, because the motion is different.

In the other problem the motion is vertical, so there is nothing analogous to a non-zero value of $\theta$ in your problem, and hence there are no terms similar to your $mg\theta$ terms.