Effect of a spring’s mass on acceleration in a mass-spring system
Suppose a mass $M$ is connected to a spring with a spring constant $k$ and mass $m$. Now, assume the system is subjected to a constant acceleration $a$, causing the spring to stretch by a constant amount $s$.
For an ideal spring, the equation governing $s$ is simply
$$
M a = ks
$$
However, how does this equation change if we consider the spring as a "real" spring, i.e., one with a finite mass $m$?
My initial thought was to replace $M$ with $M + \frac{1}{3}m$, similar to the approach used in an oscillating mass-spring system. But in deriving this "effective mass," one typically considers the kinetic energy of the spring. In an oscillating system, the velocity of a mass element $dm$ varies linearly with its distance from the fixed point, leading to the factor $\frac{1}{3}$ upon integration. This doesn’t seem applicable to the situation described here, where each element of the spring has the same velocity. If I proceed with this assumption, the integration simplifies, resulting in a factor of $1$ instead of $\frac{1}{3}$. This would suggest replacing $M$ with $M + m$ in the equation above. Yet, intuitively, this seems incorrect. Additionally, I haven't accounted for the fact that $k$ might not remain constant when integrating along the spring.
What is the correct equation and derivation for this problem?
For context, I’m trying to build a simple mechanical model of a MEMS accelerometer as suggested here, and I want to ensure I understand the correct theory first.

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/64934/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/145781/2451 and links therein.

@Qmechanic the OP had explicitly considered the integral approximation you are linking to. It is not what is being asked; that was fixed on a wall, whereas OP wants to consider constant acceleration.

@naturallyInconsistent That's why it's given as related, not duplicate

Your idea is on the right track.  If you split the spring in half and put a mass in the middle, each half will have twice the stiffness.  I'm not sure what the correct value of the mass should be - maybe $m$, maybe some scaled value as you suggest.  One way to estimate it would be to find the value of m that gives the same spring surge (internal wave) frequency.

On my part, I'm trying to see if the usual theorem of spring and constant weight cancellation would apply here too. But I'm a bit more than just tired today, so pardon as I come back to this some other day.

The mass of the spring and its compliance are continuously distributed properties. The governing equation for the displacement distribution within the spring is then a wave equation.  Is this the level of detail that you are looking for, or do you want a discrete approximation of this behavior?  If you want something discrete, then you need to specify how many degrees of freedom you want to assign to the spring.

@looksquirrel101 Why a wave equation if you consider the case of a constant stretch? The constant stretch may occur after dissipation of simply adjust it manually and then "let it go".

@Julia - Because both the mass and stiffness/compliance are distributed quantities. If I have time I will provide an answer below. The answer provided below does not account for the fact that the acceleration varies from point to point, so the question is what point is $a$ for?

@Julia - What is the boundary condition on the end of the spring that is opposite to the end with the attached mass? Is it fixed to a wall, or is it allowed to move?

Assume that the $x$-axis starts at the point mass $M$ and extends down the spring, whose length is taken to be $L$.
Draw a free-body diagram of an infinitesimal portion of the spring, and sum the forces on it. The tension $T(x)$ on one side is Taylor-series-expanded to $T(x)+\frac{dT(x)}{dx}dx$ on the other side; this accelerates the infinitesimal element (with mass $\frac{m}{L}$) at acceleration $a$. Thus,
$$\frac{dT(x)}{dx}=\frac{ma}{L}\tag{1};$$
$$T(x)=\left(M+\frac{mx}{L}\right)a,$$
where I've used the boundary condition that $T(0)=Ma$. If the spring has nonuniform mass, replace $\frac{m}{L}$ with a mass distribution $w(x)$ in Eq. (1), which may necessitate numerical solution.
The strain—if Hookean—in the infinitesimal element is $\varepsilon(x)=\frac{\sigma(x)}{E}$, with axial stress $\sigma(x)=\frac{T(x)}{A(x)}$ (cross-sectional area $A(x)$) and material Young's modulus $E$. (For a uniform spring, $E$ and $k$ are related by $k=\frac{EA}{L}$.) Integrate this strain to find the stretch $s$:
$$s=\int_0^L \varepsilon(x)\,dx=\int_0^L \frac{T(x)}{A(x)E}\,dx.$$
If the cross-sectional area is constant, then we have, via integration,
$$s=\frac{aL}{AE}\left(M+\frac{m}{2}\right).$$
So the correct replacement is $\left(M+\frac{m}{2}\right)$.
(Cheers from another MEMS engineer!)

Thanks, seems reasonable. Do you have a reference for this?

To my knowledge, just the standard engineering curriculum. Is there an unclear step?

Senturia's Microsystem Design is a more advanced general reference, though I don't believe this problem is discussed. Make sure to check the errata for typos in the text and equations.

No, every step seems to be clear. The only thing that bothers me is that I don't see, how I can analyze the situation of a simple oscillating spring to get the 1/3 m for comparison or - the other way around - how to use the energy approach to derive the 1/2 m from my question. Thanks for the book recommendation.

See Effective mass. Yes, the kinetic-energy factor is 1 at steady state. The $M +\frac{m}{2}$ factor is a different factor related to the equilibrium position.

I'm not sure that I understand this solution. Is the spring fixed at one end or are all points on the entire spring and the point mass all accelerating at $a$? Your solution is for an applied force on the end of the spring opposite to the point mass dragging them both at the constant acceleration $a$. The solution would be different if the opposite end of the spring were fixed and the point mass was accelerated at $a$.

The context ("For an ideal spring, the equation governing s
is simply Ma=ks") indicates to me that the intended interpretation is that the base to which the spring is connected is being accelerated and that a steady-state solution is sought for a nonzero spring mass.

@Chemomechanics - That's different from my interpretation. $Ma=ks$ is also the equation for a mass attached to a spring that is fixed on the other end. Your solution is certainly correct for your interpretation.

I had added a long answer on solving the wave equation with an end mass, but then deleted it because I don't think that is what the OP was asking for. If I understand correctly, the OP is interested in the approximation used to get the effective mass for different scenarios. If that is in fact the case, then the answer is simple, the approximation is for the kinematics of the spring itself. The assumption is that the displacement distribution along the spring is given as:
$$u(x,t) = u_0(t) + \frac{u_L(t) - u_0(t)}{L} x$$
where $u_0(t)$ and $u_L(t)$ are the displacement of the ends of the spring at $x=0$ and $x=L$ respectively. This approximation can then be used in any analysis.
For all of the following analyses the spring has a mass per unit length of $\mu=m/L$ and a compliance per unit length of $1/\kappa = 1/(kL)$, where $m$ is the total mass of the spring and $k$ is its total stiffness. The tension in the spring would be given as $T=\kappa \frac{du}{dx}$. For an elastic bar with Young's modulus $E$ and cross-sectional area $A$, $\kappa=EA$.
Simple harmonic oscillator with $u_0(t)=0$ and point mass $M$ at $x=L$:
$$KE+PE = \frac{1}{2}M\left(\frac{du_L}{dt}\right)^2+\int\limits_0^L \frac{1}{2}\mu \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\right)^2\,dx + \int\limits_0^L \frac{1}{2}\kappa \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2\,dx \\=\frac{1}{2}M\left(\frac{du_L}{dt}\right)^2+\frac{1}{6}m\left(\frac{du_L}{dt}\right)^2+\frac{1}{2}ku^2_L$$
Setting $\frac{d}{dt}(KE+PE)=0$ and dividing by $\frac{du_L}{dt}$ yields the equation of motion:
$$\left(M+\frac{m}{3}\right)\frac{d^2u_L}{dt^2}+ku_L=0$$
So clearly in this case the effective mass for the spring-mass system is $M+\frac{m}{3}$.
Fixed at $x=0$, end mass at $x=L$ with constant acceleration $a$ of the end mass
Here it is useful to introduce the weak form for Newton's second law for the system as:
$$M\frac{d^2u_L}{dt^2}w_L+\int\limits_0^L \mu \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}w\,dx+\int\limits_0^L \kappa \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}\,dx=F_0 w_0 + F_L w_L +\int\limits_0^L pw\,dx$$
Here, $p$ is an external applied force per unit length applied along the spring (which will usually be zero), $F_0$ and $F_L$ are external point forces applied at $x=0$ and $x=L$, and $w$ is a test function defined in a similar fashion to the assumed displacement distribution as:
$$w(x)=w_0+\frac{w_L-w_0}{L}x$$
Finally, the weak-form equation above must be valid for any arbitrary choice of the pair $w_0$ and $w_L$. The weak form leads to the following equation of motion:
$$Ma+\frac{m}{3}a+\frac{1}{2}kat^2=F_L$$
So the effective mass here would again be $M+\frac{m}{3}$.
Point mass M attached at $x=0$, constant force $F_L = (M+m)a$ applied at $x=L$ to induce a constant acceleration of the entire system
The weak form is now changed to:
$$M\frac{d^2u_0}{dt^2}w_0+\int\limits_0^L \mu \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}w\,dx+\int\limits_0^L \kappa \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}\,dx=F_0 w_0 + F_L w_L +\int\limits_0^L pw\,dx$$
Using the fact that $\frac{d^2u_0}{dt^2}=\frac{d^2u_L}{dt^2}=a$, the governing equations associated with the arbitrary choices of $w_0$ and $w_L$ are:
$$Ma+\frac{m}{2}a-k(u_L-u_0)=0 \\ \frac{m}{2}a+k(u_L-u_0)=(M+m)a$$
I'm not sure that there is a clear "effective mass" in this case. The effective mass of the system associated with the acceleration is $M+m$, and the stretch of the spring is clearly $u_L-u_0 = \left(M+\frac{m}{2}\right)a/k$. These are the same results that @Chemomechanics derived in their answer.
